# In-app purchase is allowed only with test user?

Tags: in-app-purchase, app-store-connect

Our app has a few consumable in app purchase items .
They worked great with the test user , before the release .
Now the app is at the store already , but when trying to purchase item with my apple id, it founds the item at the store, but it shows this message :

```
The is not a test user account
```

But this message should appear only if the app is not at the store yet, isn't it ?
What could go wrong here with my app ? and how it did passed the apple review ?

(must say: i have logged out from the user in settings, and it happened when trying to log in)

Thanks .

Comment: Tried also to reset device,log out, anything, no success. why i can't purchase items ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably this mistake will happened to other developers .
Problem was that after you download your own app from the store , you later put your new version from Xcode to the device,and forget about it .  Than, the app on the device is not with distribution code signing, and you can't purchase with a real Apple ID.

So , you have to download the app from the store, **or** put the app in Xcode to be on distribution than program it to the device to allow purchasing.